# Values not updating but showing rows affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2012-express

> THERE IS NO TRIGGER ON THIS TABLE.

I'm facing strange behaviour of sql server. One of the table column value not updating.

Here is the query and output:

[image: Select statement]

Now if I execute the update statement, it executes successfully:

[image: Update statement]

As per update statement all the clientId values should be 10, but it still remains 2. Here the select query result after executing update statement:

[image: Select statement]

I really don't find any possible issue of this behaviour. Please help to solve this puzzle.

This might helpfully to help me:

1. SQL Server 2012 Express
2. Table:

[image: Table visual info]

2. Schema:
   [Table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGgHZ.png)
3. If I rename the column name clientId to clientId2 or anything then update works. But if I rename the changed column name to clientId with udpated value then the updated values become 2 again.
4. If I keep the columne name same but table name change to Company2 or anything then then clientId values update fine.
5. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codenamejakir/Demo-Video/master/sqldemo.swf
6. With transaction: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codenamejakir/Demo-Video/master/SqlLive.swf

Overall I have noticed that if the table name "Company" and column name "ClientId" then column value not updating.

Thanks.

Comment: you might have a trigger on table!!

Comment: No trigger set on this table, have a look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXQNZ.png

Comment: Please replace **pictures of text** with text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add the images as text? It will make it easier to read for us.

Comment: try to commit once

Comment: I've executed the update statement withing Transaction scope but doesn't help.

Comment: Any constraints?

Comment: There is no constraints

Comment: Did you run update statement as transaction? if yes then commit it to see the results? To know open transactions run DBCC opentran.

Comment: (Once it happened to me, so you might try) Drop existing indexes and recreate them (maybe do on a backup).

Comment: I did it but no help

Comment: No idea, your video is very interesting (and Ilike that tool for showing your work, awesome).  It is like you're stuck in some automatic rollback situation.  So when you run both at the same time, its putting them as one transaction and rolling it back at the end.  Never seen anything like that before.  You dont have any third party add-ons or anything?

Comment: Could you run `SELECT        SQLTEXT.text, STATS.last_execution_time
FROM          sys.dm_exec_query_stats STATS
CROSS APPLY   sys.dm_exec_sql_text(STATS.sql_handle) AS SQLTEXT
WHERE         STATS.last_execution_time > GETDATE()-1
ORDER BY      STATS.last_execution_time DESC` to see if there have been any queries ran on the background after you do the update

Comment: @PreQL I have tested in another pc, no 3rd party tool, same issue.

Comment: Try [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql), then do the update.

Comment: No luck with "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF"

Comment: Finally the ghost is out, it was caused by a windows service that always execute the update statement behind, I created it long ago testing perpose and forgot to stop the service. :P Thanks all of you for your great help.